# Bolding lines between commonly occurring pairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to show individual changes between a pre and post treatment by connecting lines between the pre/post points.

```
df<- data.frame(col1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,
                       5,5,5,5,5,6,6,2,6,4,6,4,5,1,4,6,2,6,6,2),
                col2=c("pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre",
                       "pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre","pre",
                       "post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post",
                       "post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post","post"),
                col3=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
                       "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t",
                       "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
                       "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"))

df$col2 <- factor(df$col2, levels=c("pre", "post"))


ggplot(df, aes(x=col2, y=col1, group=col3))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.05)
```

I would like, for example, the line connecting from pre=1 to post=5 to be bold as it has the most occurrences of this specific change. Ideally, there would be a gradient from high to low occurring pairs with the highest being the most obvious line visible.

Since there are many lines stacked on top of one another I wasn't sure how to go about getting this result. I would try adding a new column via `ifelse` and adding color by that grouping but my real dataset is much larger and wouldn't be feasible.

I have tried jittering the lines but the result is very messy and not easy to understand what is being shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context as to why `ifelse()` is not feasible? How big is your dataset? Thanks

Comment: Well my real dataset has a range of potential numbers from 1 - ~50, so to type out each possible combination of changes would (I think) take an unnecessary amount of time for what I'm trying to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a different visualisation - I believe for what you want to show it would be a perfect use case.

**The alluvial chart**, here using {ggalluvial}.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(df, aes(x=col2, stratum = col1, alluvium = col3))+
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = col1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this! I was getting the feeling that I was starting with the wrong type of visualization to begin with. This shows exactly what I need it to, thanks again!